# How to use a DF Mini Player Busy Pin to start an LED Sequence?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, resistor

I'm using a DF Mini Player with my Arduino Uno project I keep getting stuck on the same point - how to trigger my LED sequence.  I discovered, through some google searching, that utilizing the BUSY pin on the DF Player Mini would return data that I was hoping I could use to trigger the sequence.

My code is as follows:

```cpp
// Wed 17 Aug 2023; Modified BUSY_PIN INPUT_PULLUP to INPUT to accomodate for player keeping track of it's own state of HIGH or LOW, fixed BAUD rate mismatch

#include <DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h>
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"
#define BUTTON_PIN 4
#define BUSY_PIN 8




bool buttonState = 1; // Normally high, goes low when pressed
bool previousButtonState = 1; // Because we will test when CHANGED

///////////////Create the Player object/////////////////////////////
DFRobotDFPlayerMini player;

static const uint8_t PIN_MP3_TX = 2; // UNO Tx connects module's RX
static const uint8_t PIN_MP3_RX = 3; // UNO Rx connects module's TX
SoftwareSerial softwareSerial(PIN_MP3_RX, PIN_MP3_TX);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////Create Fairy Light Variables////////////////////

int led = 11;           // the PWM pin the LED is attached to
int brightness = 3;    // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 2;    // how many points to fade the LED by

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int busyState = 0;
int prevBusyState = 0;

void setup()
{

  ///////////////////////Button Trigger//////////////////////////

  pinMode (BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP); // Avoids need for resistor

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  pinMode(BUSY_PIN, INPUT); //check to see if song is still playing



  ///////////////////////Music Functions/////////////////////////

  // Init USB serial port for debugging
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();
  // Init serial port for DFPlayer Mini
  softwareSerial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  // Start communication with DFPlayer Mini
  if (!player.begin(softwareSerial, true, false)) {  //Use softwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
    Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
    while (true) {
      delay(0);
    }
  }

  busyState = digitalRead(BUSY_PIN);
  prevBusyState = busyState;

  ///////////// End Music Functions/////////////////////////////


  ////////////////////Fairy Lights//////////////////////////////

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT); //declare pin 11 to be an output

  //////////////////End Fairy Light/////////////////////////////
}

void loop()
{

  buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
  busyState = digitalRead(BUSY_PIN);

  if (busyState != prevBusyState) {
    if (busyState == LOW) {
      Serial.print ("song is playing. lights are go");
      Serial.print('\n');
      Serial.print('\r');

      /////////////////Fairy Light Fading Routine////////////////////////
      // set the brightness of pin 10:
      analogWrite(led, brightness);

      // change the brightness for next time through the loop:
      brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;

      // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
      if (brightness <= 1 || brightness >= 240) {
        fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
      }
      // wait for 30 milliseconds to see the dimming effect
      delay(45);
      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    prevBusyState = busyState;
  }


  if (buttonState == LOW && previousButtonState == HIGH)
  {
    /////////////////////Play Song///////////////////////

    // The following NOT inside the previous if()
    // Set volume to maximum (0 to 30).
    player.volume(23);
    // Play the first MP3 file on the SD card
    player.play(1); // i.e. usually file 0001.mp3

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  }
  previousButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

When I check my Serial Monitor, I am getting my print `song is playing. lights are go`. However the LED (which are [Fairy Lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09DSSVW8B)) do not follow the sequence. In fact, they just stay on the entire time. I even added a 10k resistor to Data input 11 - which only dampened the light intensity but otherwise did no other effect.

I'm not sure if I will need to control these lights with another board, code is not sufficient or if I'm missing something in the wiring. I would have thought the power source would be the issue, but if the LED's are getting power through data, I would think the resistor would take care of that issue?

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with the DF player, in fact it is just clutter in the question ..... forget about the DF player for now, that part works ... write simple code that turns the lights on for one second, turns lights off for one second and repeats

Comment: so the fade code that im using in my sketch is actually part of the arduino built in examples (01. basics > fade). Which works when its not nested inside the ```if``` statement - but the tradeoff is that it "works" at all times with no trigger.

Comment: then there is something wrong with the `if` statements ... add debugging code to your program

Comment: well thats actually the thing, I put in a `Serial.print ("song is playing. lights are go");` to run if/when BUSY state is picked up by my code in the serial monitor. That does actually come through. But the Light sequence does not. Thats the thing that keeps confusing me. I thought for sure once I got my Serial Monitor to read that, I would have success, but that was not the case :(

Comment: like I said before ... write a new program that only turns the lights on and off ... no DF player code